# Add object to array if checkbox is checked, remove if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to add some objects to an array if a checkbox is checked. But I can't seem to make it work. What I would like is to add an object depending on the values of the checked checkboxes. I hope you guys can understand it. Let me show you in code :

This is the code to check if a checkbox is checked :

```
var filter_options=[];
        $('input:checkbox').click(function()
        {
          var name=$(this).val().trim();
          if(this.checked)
          {
            filter_options.push(name);
            console.log('Add: ' + name);
        }
        else
        {
            var index=filter_options.indexOf(name);
            if(index > -1)
            {
              filter_options.splice(index, 1);
              console.log('Remove: ' + name + ' at index: ' + index);
          }
      }
      $('#result').html(filter_options.join('; '));
      console.log(filter_options);
  });
```

Let's these are the object:

```
var human = new Human();
var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();

var options = []; //push the objects here depending on the checkboxes value.
```

And this is my html :

```
<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" value="human">
  <input type="checkbox" value="dog">
  <input type="checkbox" value="cat">
</div>
```

How can I add these objects to the array depending on the checkbox value? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Human() {
    this.id = 1; 
    this.firstName = "Human";
    this.lastName = "Last Name";
    this.age = 5;
    this.eyeColor = "color";
}

function Dog() {
    this.id = 2;
    this.firstName = "Dog";
    this.lastName = "Last Name";
    this.age = 5;
    this.eyeColor = "color";
}

function Cat() {
    this.id = 3;
    this.firstName = "Cat";
    this.lastName = "Last Name";
    this.age = 5;
    this.eyeColor = "color";
}
var human = new Human();
var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();
var filter_options=[];
        $('input:checkbox').click(function()
        {
          var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
          var name=$(this).val().trim();
          if(this.checked)
          {
            if(id==1){
              filter_options.push(human);
            }
            else if(id==2){
                filter_options.push(dog);
            }
            else if(id==3){
                filter_options.push(cat);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var index=filter_options.indexOf(name);
            if(index > -1)
            {
              filter_options.splice(index, 1);
              console.log('Remove: ' + name + ' at index: ' + index);
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < filter_options.length; i++) {
              if(filter_options[i].id == id) {
                  filter_options.splice(i, 1);
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      $('#result').html(filter_options.join('; '));
      console.log(filter_options);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" value="human" data-id="1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="dog" data-id="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="cat" data-id="3">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this will work fine. Is there any way I can make this dynamic? I mean let's say I have multiple objects and later on I add a few other objects as well. I would not like to change the code again since I would need to lets say:  `if(id==7){ filter_options.push(horse); }` do this. How can  I make this dynamic?? Thanks :)

Comment: To make it dynamic, you need to have a predefined array of all the animal objects data like human,dog, horse etc. Then you can do it by data-id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filter_options=[];
$(".option").change(function()
{
    $(".option").each(function()
    {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') )
        {
            var name=$(this).val().trim();
            filter_options.push(name);
            console.log('Add: ' + name);
        } else {
            var index=filter_options.indexOf(name);
            if(index > -1)
            {
              filter_options.splice(index, 1);
              console.log('Remove: ' + name + ' at index: ' + index);
          }
        }
    });
     $('#result').html(filter_options.join(': '));
      console.log(filter_options);
});
```

Comment: This will not work since the array `filter-options` is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there needs to some modification on the HTML to allow the end user to view properly using `div` and `label`.

Next, you just need the logic for addition and deletion based on the `:checked` condition.

```js
$(function() {
  clickHandler();
});

function clickHandler() {
  var options = [];
  var human = new Human();
  var dog = new Dog();
  var cat = new Cat();

  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      options.push(name);
    } else {
      options.splice(options.indexOf(name), 1);
    }
    console.log('List = ', options)
  });
}

function Human() {}

function Dog() {}

function Cat() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <div>
    <label for="human">
      <input type="checkbox" value="human" name="human" />
      Human
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="human">
      <input type="checkbox" value="dog" name="dog"/>
      Dog
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="human">
      <input type="checkbox" value="cat" name="cat"/>
      Cat
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't want to add the "cat" (cat as string) in the array but the `cat` as an object.I solved anyway thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function submitForm(frm) {
    frm.createSpinner();
    return new Promise((submitResolve, submitReject) => {
        frm.objectify().then((formData) => {
            post(frm.ga("action"), formData).then((res) => {
                submitResolve(res);
                frm.removeSpinner();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Bu ile sarmalamayı deneyebilirsiniz.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).